# Documentum DQL query to import a file form cliet machine to repository

Tags: documentum

Can anyone tell me how to import a document from client machine to documentum repository using only "DQL", below is the command I am using... it's not working thought... 
The error I am getting is `[DM_SYSOBJECT_E_CANT_ACCESS_FILE- Unable to access file due to operating system error.`

```
CREATE abc OBJECT 
set object_name='xyz', 
set folder_title='pqr', 
set doc_subtype_code='XXXX', 
set template_code='00', 
set doc_subtype_nme='abc Documents', 
set isworkflowrequired=1,
set iscreatedfrombiztemplate=0, 
set sec_classification_code='O', 
set acl_domain='myacldomain', 
set acl_name='myacl'
set product_wf_code='0'
LINK '/Cabinet123/MYDocs', 
SETFILE 'C:\mydoc.doc' WITH CONTENT_FORMAT='msw8';
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation the file to upload using setfile must either be local to the Content Server or to network locations visible to the Content Server.