# Documentum DQL Query

Tags: dql, documentum

How to create a new `dm_document` object using document from local system using DQL? I have tried the following but it's not working:

```
create dm_document object
    SET title = 'TEST',
    SET subject = 'TRIAL',
    set object_name = 'Test123',
    SETFILE 'c:\test.txt' with CONTENT_FORMAT= 'msww'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Documentum DQL query to import a file form cliet machine to repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447096/documentum-dql-query-to-import-a-file-form-cliet-machine-to-repository)

Answer (score 2):

How do you run this DQL?
If you're doing it via Documentum Administrator, Documentum looks for the file with path 'C:\test.txt' on an application server machine wherer DA runs. So if you want to upload it into documentum you must place this file into appserver machine or use another tool for execution DQL.

And could you please show us an error, that you got

Answer (score 0):

**Your DQL works for me** (!) but after clean any line-warp, so try this

```
create dm_document object SET title = 'TEST', SET subject = 'TRIAL', set object_name = 'Test123', SETFILE 'c:\test.txt' with CONTENT_FORMAT= 'msww'
```

...and be sure there is a such file on Content Server (not local) file system

good luck